# PowerShell: check if WIA (COM?) object has a specific Property

Tags: powershell, wia

I'm still relatively new to PowerShell. This is a follow up to [Use PowerShell to extract GPS Latitude etc. (Properties > Details) from an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971176/use-powershell-to-extract-gps-latitude-etc-properties-details-from-an-image) and using code like this (from @stackprotector):

```
# Create an ImageFile object and load an image file
$image = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
$image.LoadFile("C:\Absolute\path\to\my.jpg")

# Read your desirered metadata
$image.Properties.Item('GpsLatitude').Value
```

As some images have no GPS data, this gets an error. How can I check if *Properties.Item('GpsLatitude')* actually exists in that file, before trying to extract it?

Thank you.

Comment: What does `$image.Properties` by itself return? You should be able to see from there.

Comment: Thanks. It returns a whole list of

` Value          : System.__ComObject`
` Name           : 20546`
` etc`

Comment: So I can take this list and check/search for GpsLatitude somehow? Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can just dot source the property you're after and evaluate against that: `$image.Properties.GPSLatitude`.

Comment: Excellent. From what I can see - and I'm still fairly new to PowerShell - the property _$image.Properties.Item('GpsLatitude')_ **doesn't** exist if the .jpg has no GPS data recorded in it. So I need to learn how to check for that condition; ie is X in Y?, it seems.

Comment: Essentially, yeah. A simple `if` construct should do.

Comment: Ok, I can't work out the syntax of how I check if _$image.Properties.Item('GpsLatitude')_ exists in my _$image_ object (above). Anyone got a quick example of how it's done?

Comment: Can you comment what you tried?

Comment: Sure
`if(Get-Member -inputobject $image -name "Properties.Item('GpsLatitudeRef')" -Membertype Properties){Write-Out "Does exist"}` 
`if(Get-Member -inputobject $image -name "GpsLatitudeRef" -Membertype Properties.Item){Write-Out "Does exist"}`
`if(Get-Member -inputobject $image -name "GpsLatitudeRef" -Membertype Properties.Item()){Write-Out "Does exist"}`

Comment: Again, I'm still new to PS, so was trying to get clues from `$image.Properties | Get-Member` and then things like `$x = $image.Properties.Item` followed by `foreach($prop in $x) { Write-Output $prop}`

Comment: Can you just print the properties property? `$image.properties`?  Does it show the property you want in there?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific purpose, you can use the [Properties.Exists method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-iproperties-exists):

```
if ($image.Properties.Exists('GpsLatitude')) {
    $image.Properties.Item('GpsLatitude').Value
}
```

In general, you can always use [exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2).